# Why can't I use the same id in different layout for different fragements in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, textview

I have 2 fragments in my application, `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. Both are using different layouts called `content_view1` and `content_view2`. And I put both fragment into a `ViewPager`. Now see the code :
`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public ViewPager vp;
FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    vp = new ViewPager(this);
    vp.setId("VP".hashCode());
    fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    vp.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    setContentView(vp);
    vp.setCurrentItem(0);
}

}
```

`Fragment1.java`

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

MainActivity mainActivity;

public Fragment1() {
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view1, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.haiTextView)).setText("Hello");
}
}
```

`Fragment2.java`

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

MainActivity mainActivity;

public Fragment2() {
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view2, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.haiTextView)).setText("Hai");
}
}
```

`FragmentAdapter.java`

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragments.add(new Fragment1());
    mFragments.add(new Fragment2());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}
}
```

`content_view1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/haiTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`content_view2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/haiTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now you see both layout has one textView with same `id`.
When I run this application, the fragment1's `TextView` has text "hai" and fragment2's `TextView` has text "". But what I'm expecting is, the fragment1's `TextView` should have text "Hello" and fragment2's `TextView` should have text "hai".

Ok now I changed the `TextView` id of `content_view2.xml` to `haiTextView2`. Did the same in  `Fragment2.java` also. Now the application is working perfectly as I expected.

Now my questions:

**1) Why I did't get the expected out put when I keep both the `TextView` id same?

2) Why can't I use same ids here?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) Why I did't get the expected out put when I keep both the TextView
>   id same?
>
> 2) Why can't I use same ids here?

That is happening because of this line:

```
((TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.haiTextView)).setText("Hai");
```

The problem is the `findViewById()` method will return the **first** occurrence of a `View` with the provided id(it also doesn't differentiate between the layouts of the two fragments), so when you're setting the text in either the first or second fragment the `TextView` that gets set is the first one(the one from the second fragment is left untouched).

On the other hand, when you use different ids the proper `TextViews` will get selected.

You should avoid looking for the views of a `Fragment` using the `Activity` reference, fragments should be designed as loosely coupled components(it doesn't make any sense to look for the fragment's views using the activity when you could simply use `getView().findViewById(etc)`).
Also, you should really avoid using `setRetainInstance()` with fragments used in a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Why should I avoid `setRetainInstance()`

Comment: Thanks you very much. `getView()` is very useful information for me.

Comment: @VishalVijay `setRetaininstance(true)` will keep that fragment across a configuration change, on the other hand the `ViewPager` handles the fragments on his own after a rotation change. That method is not to be used with fragments in every situation.

Comment: Ok. Consider I have a layout which is having a `ListView`. I'm using a `ListFragment`. So how can i use `setListAdapter()` kind of function by using `getView()` function. (Consider this with respect to main question which I asked. ie; I have 2 fragment with a list view. I'm using `ListFragment` so that the `id` should be `@+id/list`).

Comment: @VishalVijay If you're using a `ListFragment` then the `ListView` must have an id of `android.R.id.list`(`@android:id/list` in the xml layout file), unless your fragment has more then one `ListView`. The idea was that you should pass in a `Bundle`(in the `getItem()` method of the adapter: `Bundle b = new Bundle(); b.put("position", position); mFragments.get(position).setArgs(b);return mFragments.get(position);`) the `position` for the fragment and update the fragment based on that position. Then in the fragment use `getArguments().getInt("position")` and you'll know at what page you are.

Comment: K. But what I can do with position of `Fragment`

Comment: @VishalVijay Knowing the position to which this fragment corresponds means you can set the text without calling to the activity for example: `@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.haiTextView)).setText(getArguemnts().getInt("position") == 0 ? "hello" : ""hai);}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29064/discussion-between-vishal-vijay-and-luksprog)

Comment: @Luksprog Sorry for my previous post I guess I was confused as I couldn't make my question clear to you, this is more described version of my problem also I have added suggestions by you in the previous answer . Can you please suggest me on this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18097567/1503130

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result with same ID's at different page of the view pager, You can use something like this

`TextView textView = (TextView) vp.getChildAt(vp.getCurrentItem).findViewById(R.id.haiTextView)`;